# Beginner Accordionist

Tags: accordion

I am looking to begin learning the accordion. And I’ve narrowed my choices of first accordion based on research to two accordions that I can afford. They are both practically the same price, except, now it’s between a 22 key accordion or a 31 key accordion. I’m curious if anybody can answer which is objectively better and if which one is easier to learn and master.

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ensure objective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). IMO this question ought to be valid, but it might attract close-votes since it's similar to questions like "What's the best model" (subjective) or "help me pick out my gear." I recommend editing to put more emphasis on the most answerable question, "which one is easier to learn and master." I doubt there's any way in which one is "better" except for that consideration.

Comment: As Andy said. Generally we want to avoid highly specific questions and rather have universal questions that may be useful for many people. So instead of asking "I’ve got a choice between these models, which is better?" I’d suggest you asking something like "I’ve got these choices, what things should I consider when buying a beginners instrument?". This way people with experience might give you information that is relevant to you which is currently not relevant to the question.

Comment: I know very little about the accordion but this applies to any instrument. I highly recommend trying to find a local resource to help with your decision. If you plan on taking lessons (a good idea) speak with teachers in your area for advice on what type of instrument to buy. If there are no local resources reach out to a few dealers that specialize in accordions and ask them what would be a good choice within your budget and compare notes between them. This website seems to have some good general information to educate you: https://theaccordionshop.co.uk/advice/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a [piano accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_accordion), and the number of keys mentioned are on the treble side, the main difference is that you will have less range with the 22-key than the 31-key.  Both are smaller than a standard 41-key model.

What this means is that while trying to play some pieces, you might "run out of notes" at the top or bottom.

Also important to consider is whether the bass side has a full [Stradella system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stradella_bass_system)  or if some chord buttons have been omitted.  You won't be able to learn to use the whole system if your instrument is incomplete.